# Habilitar localización sin pop up javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5, linux, programación-móvil

Es posible habilitar la localización en javascript.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
```

Sin el pop up que lo pregunta, es decir se puede hacer solo con una check box?
o una etiqueta `<button>` de html?

Comment: Sería sumamente invasivo no darle al usuario la posibilidad de decidir si desea o no compartir su ubicación a través del browser. Si simplemente se pudiera hacer con un checkbox, JS + css para invisibilizarlo permitirían olvidarse de esa restricción.

Comment: Según [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14538929/7023800) respuesta en SO [No puedes pues es una medida de seguridad](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#security).

Answer (score 0):

En teoría no debería ser posible, porque es responsabilidad del navegador solicitar ese permiso, si delegan esa responsabilidad en el desarrollo, sería bastante fácil engañar la aceptación del usuario. Lo que no implica que alguna implementación se lo salte (lo que sería bastante grave).

En [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Geolocation) se puede leer esto:

> Por razones de seguridad, cuando una página web intenta obtener acceso
>   a la información de ubicación, se notifica al usuario y le pide
>   **conceder el permiso**. Tenga en cuenta que cada navegador tiene sus
>   propias políticas y métodos para solicitar este permiso.

Y según el standard [W3c](http://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#security):

> Se DEBE proveer un mecanismo que proteja la privacidad del usuario, y
>   este mecanismo DEBERÍA  asegurar que ninguna información sobre la
>   localización este habilitada a través de esta API  sin la autorización
>   **expresa** del usuario. (traducción mía)

**Para saber la localización aproximada sin solicitar permiso** puedes leer [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017854/geolocation-without-requesting-):, básicamente lo que hace es un get a https://ipinfo.io/ que te devuelve información de ubicación (aproximada) a partir de la ip. Dale ejecutar al código de abajo (sacado de [acá](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47142775/6121568)):

```js
$.get("https://api.ipdata.co", function (response) {
    $("#response").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="response"></pre>
```

Obviamente, vpn's y y/o proxys pueden hacer que esta información no sea correcta, porque es un método totalmente diferente al que usa la API de geolocalización.